# New screen after PayPal payment

Tags: flutter, paypal

I followed this Tutorial: https://medium.com/flutter-community/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-flutter-379fbb3b87f5 showing how to implement PayPal into Flutter. I want that the the user gets redirected to another screen after the payment is done instead of the web viewer just being closed.
Can you please tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. What are you putting in onFinish parameter? Try putting print statements in the web view part of the code to check which condition is the code getting stuck at.